# Criando uma coleção

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As duas imagens são de como meu *array* está. Na primeira imagem tenho um array com 3 itens, sendo o primeiro  do mês de abril e contém 4 passagens. Para cada passagem tenho os respectivos participantes. Meu problema está sendo em mandar esse *array* para minha *view*, pois não consigo pegar algumas propriedades em tempo de execução como `passagem.participante`.

Tentei dividir isso em três *arrays*, mas quando executo via `foreach` na tela não fica exibido adequadamente com o mês e seus participantes com suas passagens.

Como fazer um array só que eu conseguisse acessar todas as propriedades e jogá-las na tela?

Segue como está a view hoje, mas preciso sincronizar as informações conforme disse antes.

```cs
@using WebProvider.BMW_Incentivo.Domain.Models
@model WebProvider.BMW_Incentivo.Admin.Models.GerenciaPassagemModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Gerenciamento de Passagens";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/css/pageDataTables.css")" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/css/tableDataTables.css")" media="screen" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/js/jquery.dataTables.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Content/js/pages/GerenciadorPassagem.js"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "GerenciaPassagem", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <fieldset id="passagem">

        <div style="float: left;">
            <label>Mês:</label>

            <select id="ListaPeriodo" name="ListaPeriodo" onchange="listaPassagensMes();">
                @foreach (var item in Model.ListaPeriodo)
                {
                    <option id="@item.Mes" value="@item.Mes">@item.DescricaoMes</option>
                }
            </select>

            <span class="error">* Campo Obrigatório</span>

        </div>
        <div style="float: right;">
            <label>Ano:</label>

            <select id="ListaAno" name="ListaAno">

                @*@foreach (int item in Model.Ano)
                {*@
                    <option id="@Model.Ano " value="@Model.Ano "> @Model.Ano</option>

                @*}*@
            </select>



            <span class="error">* Campo Obrigatório</span>

        </div>
        <table border="2" class="data display datatable" id="tabFiltra">

            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><span>Acao</span></th>
                    <th><span>Participante - CPF</span></th>
                    <th><span>Passagem</span></th>
                    <th><span>Status</span></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                @foreach (Passagem participante in Model.ListaParticipante)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="@participante.Id" name="idsCredito" value="participante.Acao" @(participante.Acao == true || participante.Acao == false ? "checked = 'checked' readonly='readonly' " : string.Empty) />
                        </td>
                        <td>

                            <label id="@participante.Participante.Id" for="participanteId"> @(participante.Passagens != null ? participante.Participante.NomeCompleto + " - " + participante.Participante.CPF : "") </label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label id="@participante.Passagens" for="participantePassagem">@(participante.Passagens.ToString() != "" ? participante.Passagens.ToString() : "") </label>

                        </td>
                        <td>

                            <label id="@participante.Acao" for="participanteAcao">@(participante.Acao == true ? "Aprovado" : participante.Acao == false ? "Recusado" : "-")</label>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>

        </table>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />

        <input type="button" value="Aprovar" id="btAprovar" onclick="Aprovar(); return false;" onblur="Reload();" style="margin-left: 9px;" />

        <input type="button" value="Recusar" id="BtRecusar" onclick="Reprovar(); return false;" style="margin-left: 9px;" />

    </fieldset>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/knockout")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
}
```

Comment: Vc ta enviando como para view, legal postar a action e a view fica mais fácil opinar!

Comment: Só para saber esse `IEnumerable<Periodo>` é a coleção responsável pelos dados inclusive os relacionados?

Comment: Sim, essa coleção eu tenho todos os dados que necessito para exibir na tela...

Comment: Então na View no `@model` coloque assim:
Coloque 
`@model IEnumerable<Periodo>` ... assim você pode acessar todos os itens por essa coleção ...

Comment: Quando fiz isso, me retornou erros nas propriedades dizendo que os métodos não estavam definidos, exemplo: Model.periodo. Abriu propriedades para eu usar linq por exemplo, mas não saberia como fazer isso... poderia me ajudar por favor

Answer (score 1):

Transforme esses metodos na sua ViewModel em propriedades que ficam consumindo o IEnumerable Periodo que foi definido pelo Controller

Por ex (Classe ViewModel: **GerenciaPassagemModel**)

```
private IEnumerable<Periodo> listaPeriodo_
public IEnumerable<Periodo> ListaPeriodo { 
   get { return this.listaPeriodo_; } 
   set { this.listaPeriodo_ = value; } //Seta pelo Controller
}

public IEnumerable<int> ListaAno {
   get { 
       foreach (Periodo p in listaPeriodo_)
       {
           yield p.Ano;
       }
   }
}

public IEnumerable<Passagem> ListaParticipante {
   get { 
       foreach (Periodo p in listaPeriodo_)
       {
           for each (Passagem ps in p.Passagem)
               yield ps;
       }
   }
}
```

Na sua view, bastaria usar:

```
@foreach (Passagem participante in Model.ListaParticipante.Distinct())
@foreach (int ano in Model.ListaAno.Distinct().OrderBy(p => p))
@foreach (Periodo periodo in Model.ListaPeriodo)
```

Comment: cara eu entendi o que vc fez, o meu unico problema é saber quais são as passagens que foram de 2014 por exemplo ou 2013. Não estou conseguindo visualizar no seu código se isso é possível, pois preciso saber quem é quem, pois na minha view quando o usuário selecionar 2014, preciso trazer todo mundo com as passagens de 2014. Obrigado

Comment: Acho mais aconselhavel voce criar uma função que faz isso na classe `periodo` que vc usa pra trazer esse `IEnumerable` onde essa função irá trazer do entity apenas as passagens de um determinado período.

Comment: @SirSmart, `Model.ListaParticipante.Distinct().Where(p.Ano = 2014)` creio que essa pagina precisa ser preparada para requisitar o servidor e trazer os resultados por requisição. Caso contrario sugiro que traga tudo e filtre pelo javascript (mais complexo)

Comment: @Fúlvio, ele disse que entendeu o que eu fiz. Removi meus comentarios.

Answer (score -1):

Não me parece ser um problema de *View*: é apenas uma característica do Entity Framework, que não carrega sozinho os participantes por ser um nível de aninhamento maior do que 1, ou seja, carrega as passagens (nível 1), mas não carrega os dados agregados de passagens (nível 2 ou mais).

Não sei como está seu código no *Controller*, mas recomendaria usar o método `.Include()` para forçar a carga dos dados agregados. Por exemplo:

```
var gerenciaPassagens = context.GerenciaPassagensModels
    .Include(gp => gp.Passagem.Participante)
    .Where(/* Seus parâmetros para carga das informações */)

return View(gerenciaPassagens);
```